# Slide and Swipe Menu closing with a width percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, swipe

I am using the Slide and Swipe Menu and I am having an issue figuring out how to get the menu to close with the toggle button. For some reason in the snippet I could not get it to perform the same as mine, but in the snippet the menu doesn't close at all. On my page, the menu only closes 280px.

I initially thought that the speed parameter, `speed: 280,` was the cause of this, but I tried changing it to 100%, but it didn't work.

I am using percentage widths rather than px's for my menu. This may be the cause of this issue.

Does anyone see why the menu isn't closing or isn't closing the whole width `%` of my menu?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzd0yqLr/)

```js
!function(factory){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define.amd.jQuery?define(["jquery"],factory):factory("undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function($){"use strict";function init(options){return!options||void 0!==options.allowPageScroll||void 0===options.swipe&&void 0===options.swipeStatus||(options.allowPageScroll=NONE),void 0!==options.click&&void 0===options.tap&&(options.tap=options.click),options||(options={}),options=$.extend({},$.fn.swipe.defaults,options),this.each(function(){var $this=$(this),plugin=$this.data(PLUGIN_NS);plugin||(plugin=new TouchSwipe(this,options),$this.data(PLUGIN_NS,plugin))})}function TouchSwipe(element,options){function touchStart(jqEvent){if(!(getTouchInProgress()||$(jqEvent.target).closest(options.excludedElements,$element).length>0)){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent;if(!event.pointerType||"mouse"!=event.pointerType||0!=options.fallbackToMouseEvents){var ret,touches=event.touches,evt=touches?touches[0]:event;return phase=PHASE_START,touches?fingerCount=touches.length:options.preventDefaultEvents!==!1&&jqEvent.preventDefault(),distance=0,direction=null,currentDirection=null,pinchDirection=null,duration=0,startTouchesDistance=0,endTouchesDistance=0,pinchZoom=1,pinchDistance=0,maximumsMap=createMaximumsData(),cancelMultiFingerRelease(),createFingerData(0,evt),!touches||fingerCount===options.fingers||options.fingers===ALL_FINGERS||hasPinches()?(startTime=getTimeStamp(),2==fingerCount&&(createFingerData(1,touches[1]),startTouchesDistance=endTouchesDistance=calculateTouchesDistance(fingerData[0].start,fingerData[1].start)),(options.swipeStatus||options.pinchStatus)&&(ret=triggerHandler(event,phase))):ret=!1,ret===!1?(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase),ret):(options.hold&&(holdTimeout=setTimeout($.proxy(function(){$element.trigger("hold",[event.target]),options.hold&&(ret=options.hold.call($element,event,event.target))},this),options.longTapThreshold)),setTouchInProgress(!0),null)}}}function touchMove(jqEvent){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent;if(phase!==PHASE_END&&phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&!inMultiFingerRelease()){var ret,touches=event.touches,evt=touches?touches[0]:event,currentFinger=updateFingerData(evt);if(endTime=getTimeStamp(),touches&&(fingerCount=touches.length),options.hold&&clearTimeout(holdTimeout),phase=PHASE_MOVE,2==fingerCount&&(0==startTouchesDistance?(createFingerData(1,touches[1]),startTouchesDistance=endTouchesDistance=calculateTouchesDistance(fingerData[0].start,fingerData[1].start)):(updateFingerData(touches[1]),endTouchesDistance=calculateTouchesDistance(fingerData[0].end,fingerData[1].end),pinchDirection=calculatePinchDirection(fingerData[0].end,fingerData[1].end)),pinchZoom=calculatePinchZoom(startTouchesDistance,endTouchesDistance),pinchDistance=Math.abs(startTouchesDistance-endTouchesDistance)),fingerCount===options.fingers||options.fingers===ALL_FINGERS||!touches||hasPinches()){if(direction=calculateDirection(currentFinger.start,currentFinger.end),currentDirection=calculateDirection(currentFinger.last,currentFinger.end),validateDefaultEvent(jqEvent,currentDirection),distance=calculateDistance(currentFinger.start,currentFinger.end),duration=calculateDuration(),setMaxDistance(direction,distance),ret=triggerHandler(event,phase),!options.triggerOnTouchEnd||options.triggerOnTouchLeave){var inBounds=!0;if(options.triggerOnTouchLeave){var bounds=getbounds(this);inBounds=isInBounds(currentFinger.end,bounds)}!options.triggerOnTouchEnd&&inBounds?phase=getNextPhase(PHASE_MOVE):options.triggerOnTouchLeave&&!inBounds&&(phase=getNextPhase(PHASE_END)),phase!=PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!=PHASE_END||triggerHandler(event,phase)}}else phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase);ret===!1&&(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase))}}function touchEnd(jqEvent){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent,touches=event.touches;if(touches){if(touches.length&&!inMultiFingerRelease())return startMultiFingerRelease(event),!0;if(touches.length&&inMultiFingerRelease())return!0}return inMultiFingerRelease()&&(fingerCount=fingerCountAtRelease),endTime=getTimeStamp(),duration=calculateDuration(),didSwipeBackToCancel()||!validateSwipeDistance()?(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase)):options.triggerOnTouchEnd||options.triggerOnTouchEnd===!1&&phase===PHASE_MOVE?(options.preventDefaultEvents!==!1&&jqEvent.preventDefault(),phase=PHASE_END,triggerHandler(event,phase)):!options.triggerOnTouchEnd&&hasTap()?(phase=PHASE_END,triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,TAP)):phase===PHASE_MOVE&&(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase)),setTouchInProgress(!1),null}function touchCancel(){fingerCount=0,endTime=0,startTime=0,startTouchesDistance=0,endTouchesDistance=0,pinchZoom=1,cancelMultiFingerRelease(),setTouchInProgress(!1)}function touchLeave(jqEvent){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent;options.triggerOnTouchLeave&&(phase=getNextPhase(PHASE_END),triggerHandler(event,phase))}function removeListeners(){$element.unbind(START_EV,touchStart),$element.unbind(CANCEL_EV,touchCancel),$element.unbind(MOVE_EV,touchMove),$element.unbind(END_EV,touchEnd),LEAVE_EV&&$element.unbind(LEAVE_EV,touchLeave),setTouchInProgress(!1)}function getNextPhase(currentPhase){var nextPhase=currentPhase,validTime=validateSwipeTime(),validDistance=validateSwipeDistance(),didCancel=didSwipeBackToCancel();return!validTime||didCancel?nextPhase=PHASE_CANCEL:!validDistance||currentPhase!=PHASE_MOVE||options.triggerOnTouchEnd&&!options.triggerOnTouchLeave?!validDistance&&currentPhase==PHASE_END&&options.triggerOnTouchLeave&&(nextPhase=PHASE_CANCEL):nextPhase=PHASE_END,nextPhase}function triggerHandler(event,phase){var ret,touches=event.touches;return(didSwipe()||hasSwipes())&&(ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,SWIPE)),(didPinch()||hasPinches())&&ret!==!1&&(ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,PINCH)),didDoubleTap()&&ret!==!1?ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,DOUBLE_TAP):didLongTap()&&ret!==!1?ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,LONG_TAP):didTap()&&ret!==!1&&(ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,TAP)),phase===PHASE_CANCEL&&touchCancel(event),phase===PHASE_END&&(touches?touches.length||touchCancel(event):touchCancel(event)),ret}function triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,gesture){var ret;if(gesture==SWIPE){if($element.trigger("swipeStatus",[phase,direction||null,distance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeStatus&&(ret=options.swipeStatus.call($element,event,phase,direction||null,distance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection),ret===!1))return!1;if(phase==PHASE_END&&validateSwipe()){if(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),clearTimeout(holdTimeout),$element.trigger("swipe",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipe&&(ret=options.swipe.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection),ret===!1))return!1;switch(direction){case LEFT:$element.trigger("swipeLeft",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeLeft&&(ret=options.swipeLeft.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection));break;case RIGHT:$element.trigger("swipeRight",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeRight&&(ret=options.swipeRight.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection));break;case UP:$element.trigger("swipeUp",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeUp&&(ret=options.swipeUp.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection));break;case DOWN:$element.trigger("swipeDown",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeDown&&(ret=options.swipeDown.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection))}}}if(gesture==PINCH){if($element.trigger("pinchStatus",[phase,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData]),options.pinchStatus&&(ret=options.pinchStatus.call($element,event,phase,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData),ret===!1))return!1;if(phase==PHASE_END&&validatePinch())switch(pinchDirection){case IN:$element.trigger("pinchIn",[pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData]),options.pinchIn&&(ret=options.pinchIn.call($element,event,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData));break;case OUT:$element.trigger("pinchOut",[pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData]),options.pinchOut&&(ret=options.pinchOut.call($element,event,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData))}}return gesture==TAP?phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!==PHASE_END||(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),clearTimeout(holdTimeout),hasDoubleTap()&&!inDoubleTap()?(doubleTapStartTime=getTimeStamp(),singleTapTimeout=setTimeout($.proxy(function(){doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("tap",[event.target]),options.tap&&(ret=options.tap.call($element,event,event.target))},this),options.doubleTapThreshold)):(doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("tap",[event.target]),options.tap&&(ret=options.tap.call($element,event,event.target)))):gesture==DOUBLE_TAP?phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!==PHASE_END||(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),clearTimeout(holdTimeout),doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("doubletap",[event.target]),options.doubleTap&&(ret=options.doubleTap.call($element,event,event.target))):gesture==LONG_TAP&&(phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!==PHASE_END||(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("longtap",[event.target]),options.longTap&&(ret=options.longTap.call($element,event,event.target)))),ret}function validateSwipeDistance(){var valid=!0;return null!==options.threshold&&(valid=distance>=options.threshold),valid}function didSwipeBackToCancel(){var cancelled=!1;return null!==options.cancelThreshold&&null!==direction&&(cancelled=getMaxDistance(direction)-distance>=options.cancelThreshold),cancelled}function validatePinchDistance(){return null!==options.pinchThreshold?pinchDistance>=options.pinchThreshold:!0}function validateSwipeTime(){var result;return result=options.maxTimeThreshold?!(duration>=options.maxTimeThreshold):!0}function validateDefaultEvent(jqEvent,direction){if(options.preventDefaultEvents!==!1)if(options.allowPageScroll===NONE)jqEvent.preventDefault();else{var auto=options.allowPageScroll===AUTO;switch(direction){case LEFT:(options.swipeLeft&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=HORIZONTAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case RIGHT:(options.swipeRight&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=HORIZONTAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case UP:(options.swipeUp&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=VERTICAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case DOWN:(options.swipeDown&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=VERTICAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case NONE:}}}function validatePinch(){var hasCorrectFingerCount=validateFingers(),hasEndPoint=validateEndPoint(),hasCorrectDistance=validatePinchDistance();return hasCorrectFingerCount&&hasEndPoint&&hasCorrectDistance}function hasPinches(){return!!(options.pinchStatus||options.pinchIn||options.pinchOut)}function didPinch(){return!(!validatePinch()||!hasPinches())}function validateSwipe(){var hasValidTime=validateSwipeTime(),hasValidDistance=validateSwipeDistance(),hasCorrectFingerCount=validateFingers(),hasEndPoint=validateEndPoint(),didCancel=didSwipeBackToCancel(),valid=!didCancel&&hasEndPoint&&hasCorrectFingerCount&&hasValidDistance&&hasValidTime;return valid}function hasSwipes(){return!!(options.swipe||options.swipeStatus||options.swipeLeft||options.swipeRight||options.swipeUp||options.swipeDown)}function didSwipe(){return!(!validateSwipe()||!hasSwipes())}function validateFingers(){return fingerCount===options.fingers||options.fingers===ALL_FINGERS||!SUPPORTS_TOUCH}function validateEndPoint(){return 0!==fingerData[0].end.x}function hasTap(){return!!options.tap}function hasDoubleTap(){return!!options.doubleTap}function hasLongTap(){return!!options.longTap}function validateDoubleTap(){if(null==doubleTapStartTime)return!1;var now=getTimeStamp();return hasDoubleTap()&&now-doubleTapStartTime<=options.doubleTapThreshold}function inDoubleTap(){return validateDoubleTap()}function validateTap(){return(1===fingerCount||!SUPPORTS_TOUCH)&&(isNaN(distance)||distance<options.threshold)}function validateLongTap(){return duration>options.longTapThreshold&&DOUBLE_TAP_THRESHOLD>distance}function didTap(){return!(!validateTap()||!hasTap())}function didDoubleTap(){return!(!validateDoubleTap()||!hasDoubleTap())}function didLongTap(){return!(!validateLongTap()||!hasLongTap())}function startMultiFingerRelease(event){previousTouchEndTime=getTimeStamp(),fingerCountAtRelease=event.touches.length+1}function cancelMultiFingerRelease(){previousTouchEndTime=0,fingerCountAtRelease=0}function inMultiFingerRelease(){var withinThreshold=!1;if(previousTouchEndTime){var diff=getTimeStamp()-previousTouchEndTime;diff<=options.fingerReleaseThreshold&&(withinThreshold=!0)}return withinThreshold}function getTouchInProgress(){return!($element.data(PLUGIN_NS+"_intouch")!==!0)}function setTouchInProgress(val){$element&&(val===!0?($element.bind(MOVE_EV,touchMove),$element.bind(END_EV,touchEnd),LEAVE_EV&&$element.bind(LEAVE_EV,touchLeave)):($element.unbind(MOVE_EV,touchMove,!1),$element.unbind(END_EV,touchEnd,!1),LEAVE_EV&&$element.unbind(LEAVE_EV,touchLeave,!1)),$element.data(PLUGIN_NS+"_intouch",val===!0))}function createFingerData(id,evt){var f={start:{x:0,y:0},last:{x:0,y:0},end:{x:0,y:0}};return f.start.x=f.last.x=f.end.x=evt.pageX||evt.clientX,f.start.y=f.last.y=f.end.y=evt.pageY||evt.clientY,fingerData[id]=f,f}function updateFingerData(evt){var id=void 0!==evt.identifier?evt.identifier:0,f=getFingerData(id);return null===f&&(f=createFingerData(id,evt)),f.last.x=f.end.x,f.last.y=f.end.y,f.end.x=evt.pageX||evt.clientX,f.end.y=evt.pageY||evt.clientY,f}function getFingerData(id){return fingerData[id]||null}function setMaxDistance(direction,distance){direction!=NONE&&(distance=Math.max(distance,getMaxDistance(direction)),maximumsMap[direction].distance=distance)}function getMaxDistance(direction){return maximumsMap[direction]?maximumsMap[direction].distance:void 0}function createMaximumsData(){var maxData={};return maxData[LEFT]=createMaximumVO(LEFT),maxData[RIGHT]=createMaximumVO(RIGHT),maxData[UP]=createMaximumVO(UP),maxData[DOWN]=createMaximumVO(DOWN),maxData}function createMaximumVO(dir){return{direction:dir,distance:0}}function calculateDuration(){return endTime-startTime}function calculateTouchesDistance(startPoint,endPoint){var diffX=Math.abs(startPoint.x-endPoint.x),diffY=Math.abs(startPoint.y-endPoint.y);return Math.round(Math.sqrt(diffX*diffX+diffY*diffY))}function calculatePinchZoom(startDistance,endDistance){var percent=endDistance/startDistance*1;return percent.toFixed(2)}function calculatePinchDirection(){return 1>pinchZoom?OUT:IN}function calculateDistance(startPoint,endPoint){return Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPoint.x-startPoint.x,2)+Math.pow(endPoint.y-startPoint.y,2)))}function calculateAngle(startPoint,endPoint){var x=startPoint.x-endPoint.x,y=endPoint.y-startPoint.y,r=Math.atan2(y,x),angle=Math.round(180*r/Math.PI);return 0>angle&&(angle=360-Math.abs(angle)),angle}function calculateDirection(startPoint,endPoint){if(comparePoints(startPoint,endPoint))return NONE;var angle=calculateAngle(startPoint,endPoint);return 45>=angle&&angle>=0?LEFT:360>=angle&&angle>=315?LEFT:angle>=135&&225>=angle?RIGHT:angle>45&&135>angle?DOWN:UP}function getTimeStamp(){var now=new Date;return now.getTime()}function getbounds(el){el=$(el);var offset=el.offset(),bounds={left:offset.left,right:offset.left+el.outerWidth(),top:offset.top,bottom:offset.top+el.outerHeight()};return bounds}function isInBounds(point,bounds){return point.x>bounds.left&&point.x<bounds.right&&point.y>bounds.top&&point.y<bounds.bottom}function comparePoints(pointA,pointB){return pointA.x==pointB.x&&pointA.y==pointB.y}var options=$.extend({},options),useTouchEvents=SUPPORTS_TOUCH||SUPPORTS_POINTER||!options.fallbackToMouseEvents,START_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerDown":"pointerdown":"touchstart":"mousedown",MOVE_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerMove":"pointermove":"touchmove":"mousemove",END_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerUp":"pointerup":"touchend":"mouseup",LEAVE_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?"mouseleave":null:"mouseleave",CANCEL_EV=SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerCancel":"pointercancel":"touchcancel",distance=0,direction=null,currentDirection=null,duration=0,startTouchesDistance=0,endTouchesDistance=0,pinchZoom=1,pinchDistance=0,pinchDirection=0,maximumsMap=null,$element=$(element),phase="start",fingerCount=0,fingerData={},startTime=0,endTime=0,previousTouchEndTime=0,fingerCountAtRelease=0,doubleTapStartTime=0,singleTapTimeout=null,holdTimeout=null;try{$element.bind(START_EV,touchStart),$element.bind(CANCEL_EV,touchCancel)}catch(e){$.error("events not supported "+START_EV+","+CANCEL_EV+" on jQuery.swipe")}this.enable=function(){return this.disable(),$element.bind(START_EV,touchStart),$element.bind(CANCEL_EV,touchCancel),$element},this.disable=function(){return removeListeners(),$element},this.destroy=function(){removeListeners(),$element.data(PLUGIN_NS,null),$element=null},this.option=function(property,value){if("object"==typeof property)options=$.extend(options,property);else if(void 0!==options[property]){if(void 0===value)return options[property];options[property]=value}else{if(!property)return options;$.error("Option "+property+" does not exist on jQuery.swipe.options")}return null}}var VERSION="1.6.17",LEFT="left",RIGHT="right",UP="up",DOWN="down",IN="in",OUT="out",NONE="none",AUTO="auto",SWIPE="swipe",PINCH="pinch",TAP="tap",DOUBLE_TAP="doubletap",LONG_TAP="longtap",HORIZONTAL="horizontal",VERTICAL="vertical",ALL_FINGERS="all",DOUBLE_TAP_THRESHOLD=10,PHASE_START="start",PHASE_MOVE="move",PHASE_END="end",PHASE_CANCEL="cancel",SUPPORTS_TOUCH="ontouchstart"in window,SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10=window.navigator.msPointerEnabled&&!window.navigator.pointerEnabled&&!SUPPORTS_TOUCH,SUPPORTS_POINTER=(window.navigator.pointerEnabled||window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)&&!SUPPORTS_TOUCH,PLUGIN_NS="TouchSwipe",defaults={fingers:1,threshold:75,cancelThreshold:null,pinchThreshold:20,maxTimeThreshold:null,fingerReleaseThreshold:250,longTapThreshold:500,doubleTapThreshold:200,swipe:null,swipeLeft:null,swipeRight:null,swipeUp:null,swipeDown:null,swipeStatus:null,pinchIn:null,pinchOut:null,pinchStatus:null,click:null,tap:null,doubleTap:null,longTap:null,hold:null,triggerOnTouchEnd:!0,triggerOnTouchLeave:!1,allowPageScroll:"auto",fallbackToMouseEvents:!0,excludedElements:".noSwipe",preventDefaultEvents:!0};$.fn.swipe=function(method){var $this=$(this),plugin=$this.data(PLUGIN_NS);if(plugin&&"string"==typeof method){if(plugin[method])return plugin[method].apply(plugin,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));$.error("Method "+method+" does not exist on jQuery.swipe")}else if(plugin&&"object"==typeof method)plugin.option.apply(plugin,arguments);else if(!(plugin||"object"!=typeof method&&method))return init.apply(this,arguments);return $this},$.fn.swipe.version=VERSION,$.fn.swipe.defaults=defaults,$.fn.swipe.phases={PHASE_START:PHASE_START,PHASE_MOVE:PHASE_MOVE,PHASE_END:PHASE_END,PHASE_CANCEL:PHASE_CANCEL},$.fn.swipe.directions={LEFT:LEFT,RIGHT:RIGHT,UP:UP,DOWN:DOWN,IN:IN,OUT:OUT},$.fn.swipe.pageScroll={NONE:NONE,HORIZONTAL:HORIZONTAL,VERTICAL:VERTICAL,AUTO:AUTO},$.fn.swipe.fingers={ONE:1,TWO:2,THREE:3,FOUR:4,FIVE:5,ALL:ALL_FINGERS}});

/**
 * Slide and swipe menu (https://github.com/JoanClaret/slide-and-swipe-menu)
 *
 * @copyright Copyright 2013-2015 Joan claret
 * @license   MIT
 * @author    Joan Claret Teruel <dpam23 at gmail dot com>
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
 * Copyright (c) Joan Claret Teruel <dpam23 at gmail dot com>
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the 'Software'), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED 'AS IS', WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */


;(function($, document, window, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    var slideAndSwipe =

        $.fn.slideAndSwipe = function(options) {

            var nav = $(this); // get the element to swipe
            var navWidth = -nav.outerWidth();
            var transInitial = navWidth;
   var unit = 'px';

            // get settings
            var settings = $.extend({
                triggerOnTouchEnd   : true,
                swipeStatus         : swipeStatus,
                allowPageScroll     : 'vertical',
                threshold           : 100,
                excludedElements    : 'label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe',
                speed               : 280,
    percentage          : true

            }, options );
   if (settings.percentage) {
    navWidth = -100;
    unit = '%';
            }
            nav.swipe(settings);

            /**
             * Catch each phase of the swipe.
             * move : we drag the navigation
             * cancel : open navigation
             * end : close navigation
             */
            function swipeStatus(event, phase, direction, distance) {
                if(phase == 'start') {
                    if(nav.hasClass('ssm-nav-visible')) {
                        transInitial = 0;
                    } else {
                        transInitial = 0;
                    }
                }
                var mDistance;

                if (phase == 'move' && (direction == 'left')) {
                    if(transInitial < 0) {

                        mDistance = transInitial - distance;
                    } else {
                        mDistance = -distance;
                    }

                    scrollNav(mDistance, 0);

                } else if (phase == 'move' && direction == 'right') {
                    if(transInitial < 0) {
                        mDistance = transInitial + distance;
                    } else {
                        mDistance = distance;
                    }
                    scrollNav(mDistance, 0);
                } else if (phase == 'cancel' && (direction == 'right') && transInitial === 0) {
                    scrollNav(0, settings.speed);
                } else if (phase == 'end' && (direction == 'right')) {

                       hideNavigation();
                } else if ((phase == 'end' || phase == 'cancel') && (direction == 'left')) {
                    console.log('end');
                }
            }

            /**
             * Browser detect
             */
            function isSafari() {
                return /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
            }

            function isChrome() {
                return /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
            }

            /**
             * Manually update the position of the nav on drag
             */
            function scrollNav(distance, duration) {
                nav.css('transition-duration', (duration / 1000).toFixed(1) + 's');

                // if(distance >= 0) {
                //     distance = 0;
                // }
                if(distance <= 0) {
                    distance = 0;
                }
                if(isSafari() || isChrome()) {
                   //nav.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(' + distance + 'px,0)');
     nav.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(' + distance + unit + ',0)');
    }
                else{
                  // nav.css('transform', 'translate(' + distance + 'px,0)');
     nav.css('transform', 'translate(' + distance + unit + ',0)');
    }
                if(distance == '0') {
                    $('.ssm-toggle-nav').addClass('ssm-nav-visible');
                    $('html').addClass('is-navOpen');
                    $('.ssm-overlay').fadeIn();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Open / close by click on burger icon
             */
            var hideNavigation = (function() {
                nav.removeClass('ssm-nav-visible');
                scrollNav(-280, settings.speed);
                $('html').removeClass('is-navOpen');
                $('.ssm-overlay').fadeOut();
    nav.addClass('close');
            });

            var showNavigation = (function() {
                nav.addClass('ssm-nav-visible');
                scrollNav(0, settings.speed);
            });

            $('.ssm-toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
                if(nav.hasClass('ssm-nav-visible')) {
                    hideNavigation();
                }
                else{
                    showNavigation();

                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    ;
})(window.jQuery || window.$, document, window);



/*
 * Export as a CommonJS module
 */
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = slideAndSwipe;
}


$('#proposal-panel').slideAndSwipe();
```

```css
#proposal-panel {
 background: #333333;
 width: 58%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 15px 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 /*overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: visible;*/
   transform: translate(100%,0);
}
#proposal-panel.close {
 transform: translate(0,0);
}

/*Add to panel style sheet or header sheet*/
/* overlay layer */
.ssm-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* prevent scroll when panel is open */
.is-navOpen{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ssm-toggle-nav" href="#" title="Open / close">Open</a>
 <div id="proposal-panel" class="swipe">
  <h3 id="panel-title">Proposal</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="ssm-overlay ssm-toggle-nav"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you did find solution or not, but here your solution.

Instead of `nav.addClass('close');` i added `nav.css('transform', 'translate(100%,0)');`

and removed from styles `#proposal-panel.close {transform: translate(0,0);}`

```js
!function(factory){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd&&define.amd.jQuery?define(["jquery"],factory):factory("undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function($){"use strict";function init(options){return!options||void 0!==options.allowPageScroll||void 0===options.swipe&&void 0===options.swipeStatus||(options.allowPageScroll=NONE),void 0!==options.click&&void 0===options.tap&&(options.tap=options.click),options||(options={}),options=$.extend({},$.fn.swipe.defaults,options),this.each(function(){var $this=$(this),plugin=$this.data(PLUGIN_NS);plugin||(plugin=new TouchSwipe(this,options),$this.data(PLUGIN_NS,plugin))})}function TouchSwipe(element,options){function touchStart(jqEvent){if(!(getTouchInProgress()||$(jqEvent.target).closest(options.excludedElements,$element).length>0)){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent;if(!event.pointerType||"mouse"!=event.pointerType||0!=options.fallbackToMouseEvents){var ret,touches=event.touches,evt=touches?touches[0]:event;return phase=PHASE_START,touches?fingerCount=touches.length:options.preventDefaultEvents!==!1&&jqEvent.preventDefault(),distance=0,direction=null,currentDirection=null,pinchDirection=null,duration=0,startTouchesDistance=0,endTouchesDistance=0,pinchZoom=1,pinchDistance=0,maximumsMap=createMaximumsData(),cancelMultiFingerRelease(),createFingerData(0,evt),!touches||fingerCount===options.fingers||options.fingers===ALL_FINGERS||hasPinches()?(startTime=getTimeStamp(),2==fingerCount&&(createFingerData(1,touches[1]),startTouchesDistance=endTouchesDistance=calculateTouchesDistance(fingerData[0].start,fingerData[1].start)),(options.swipeStatus||options.pinchStatus)&&(ret=triggerHandler(event,phase))):ret=!1,ret===!1?(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase),ret):(options.hold&&(holdTimeout=setTimeout($.proxy(function(){$element.trigger("hold",[event.target]),options.hold&&(ret=options.hold.call($element,event,event.target))},this),options.longTapThreshold)),setTouchInProgress(!0),null)}}}function touchMove(jqEvent){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent;if(phase!==PHASE_END&&phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&!inMultiFingerRelease()){var ret,touches=event.touches,evt=touches?touches[0]:event,currentFinger=updateFingerData(evt);if(endTime=getTimeStamp(),touches&&(fingerCount=touches.length),options.hold&&clearTimeout(holdTimeout),phase=PHASE_MOVE,2==fingerCount&&(0==startTouchesDistance?(createFingerData(1,touches[1]),startTouchesDistance=endTouchesDistance=calculateTouchesDistance(fingerData[0].start,fingerData[1].start)):(updateFingerData(touches[1]),endTouchesDistance=calculateTouchesDistance(fingerData[0].end,fingerData[1].end),pinchDirection=calculatePinchDirection(fingerData[0].end,fingerData[1].end)),pinchZoom=calculatePinchZoom(startTouchesDistance,endTouchesDistance),pinchDistance=Math.abs(startTouchesDistance-endTouchesDistance)),fingerCount===options.fingers||options.fingers===ALL_FINGERS||!touches||hasPinches()){if(direction=calculateDirection(currentFinger.start,currentFinger.end),currentDirection=calculateDirection(currentFinger.last,currentFinger.end),validateDefaultEvent(jqEvent,currentDirection),distance=calculateDistance(currentFinger.start,currentFinger.end),duration=calculateDuration(),setMaxDistance(direction,distance),ret=triggerHandler(event,phase),!options.triggerOnTouchEnd||options.triggerOnTouchLeave){var inBounds=!0;if(options.triggerOnTouchLeave){var bounds=getbounds(this);inBounds=isInBounds(currentFinger.end,bounds)}!options.triggerOnTouchEnd&&inBounds?phase=getNextPhase(PHASE_MOVE):options.triggerOnTouchLeave&&!inBounds&&(phase=getNextPhase(PHASE_END)),phase!=PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!=PHASE_END||triggerHandler(event,phase)}}else phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase);ret===!1&&(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase))}}function touchEnd(jqEvent){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent,touches=event.touches;if(touches){if(touches.length&&!inMultiFingerRelease())return startMultiFingerRelease(event),!0;if(touches.length&&inMultiFingerRelease())return!0}return inMultiFingerRelease()&&(fingerCount=fingerCountAtRelease),endTime=getTimeStamp(),duration=calculateDuration(),didSwipeBackToCancel()||!validateSwipeDistance()?(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase)):options.triggerOnTouchEnd||options.triggerOnTouchEnd===!1&&phase===PHASE_MOVE?(options.preventDefaultEvents!==!1&&jqEvent.preventDefault(),phase=PHASE_END,triggerHandler(event,phase)):!options.triggerOnTouchEnd&&hasTap()?(phase=PHASE_END,triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,TAP)):phase===PHASE_MOVE&&(phase=PHASE_CANCEL,triggerHandler(event,phase)),setTouchInProgress(!1),null}function touchCancel(){fingerCount=0,endTime=0,startTime=0,startTouchesDistance=0,endTouchesDistance=0,pinchZoom=1,cancelMultiFingerRelease(),setTouchInProgress(!1)}function touchLeave(jqEvent){var event=jqEvent.originalEvent?jqEvent.originalEvent:jqEvent;options.triggerOnTouchLeave&&(phase=getNextPhase(PHASE_END),triggerHandler(event,phase))}function removeListeners(){$element.unbind(START_EV,touchStart),$element.unbind(CANCEL_EV,touchCancel),$element.unbind(MOVE_EV,touchMove),$element.unbind(END_EV,touchEnd),LEAVE_EV&&$element.unbind(LEAVE_EV,touchLeave),setTouchInProgress(!1)}function getNextPhase(currentPhase){var nextPhase=currentPhase,validTime=validateSwipeTime(),validDistance=validateSwipeDistance(),didCancel=didSwipeBackToCancel();return!validTime||didCancel?nextPhase=PHASE_CANCEL:!validDistance||currentPhase!=PHASE_MOVE||options.triggerOnTouchEnd&&!options.triggerOnTouchLeave?!validDistance&&currentPhase==PHASE_END&&options.triggerOnTouchLeave&&(nextPhase=PHASE_CANCEL):nextPhase=PHASE_END,nextPhase}function triggerHandler(event,phase){var ret,touches=event.touches;return(didSwipe()||hasSwipes())&&(ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,SWIPE)),(didPinch()||hasPinches())&&ret!==!1&&(ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,PINCH)),didDoubleTap()&&ret!==!1?ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,DOUBLE_TAP):didLongTap()&&ret!==!1?ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,LONG_TAP):didTap()&&ret!==!1&&(ret=triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,TAP)),phase===PHASE_CANCEL&&touchCancel(event),phase===PHASE_END&&(touches?touches.length||touchCancel(event):touchCancel(event)),ret}function triggerHandlerForGesture(event,phase,gesture){var ret;if(gesture==SWIPE){if($element.trigger("swipeStatus",[phase,direction||null,distance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeStatus&&(ret=options.swipeStatus.call($element,event,phase,direction||null,distance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection),ret===!1))return!1;if(phase==PHASE_END&&validateSwipe()){if(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),clearTimeout(holdTimeout),$element.trigger("swipe",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipe&&(ret=options.swipe.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection),ret===!1))return!1;switch(direction){case LEFT:$element.trigger("swipeLeft",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeLeft&&(ret=options.swipeLeft.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection));break;case RIGHT:$element.trigger("swipeRight",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeRight&&(ret=options.swipeRight.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection));break;case UP:$element.trigger("swipeUp",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeUp&&(ret=options.swipeUp.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection));break;case DOWN:$element.trigger("swipeDown",[direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection]),options.swipeDown&&(ret=options.swipeDown.call($element,event,direction,distance,duration,fingerCount,fingerData,currentDirection))}}}if(gesture==PINCH){if($element.trigger("pinchStatus",[phase,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData]),options.pinchStatus&&(ret=options.pinchStatus.call($element,event,phase,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData),ret===!1))return!1;if(phase==PHASE_END&&validatePinch())switch(pinchDirection){case IN:$element.trigger("pinchIn",[pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData]),options.pinchIn&&(ret=options.pinchIn.call($element,event,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData));break;case OUT:$element.trigger("pinchOut",[pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData]),options.pinchOut&&(ret=options.pinchOut.call($element,event,pinchDirection||null,pinchDistance||0,duration||0,fingerCount,pinchZoom,fingerData))}}return gesture==TAP?phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!==PHASE_END||(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),clearTimeout(holdTimeout),hasDoubleTap()&&!inDoubleTap()?(doubleTapStartTime=getTimeStamp(),singleTapTimeout=setTimeout($.proxy(function(){doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("tap",[event.target]),options.tap&&(ret=options.tap.call($element,event,event.target))},this),options.doubleTapThreshold)):(doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("tap",[event.target]),options.tap&&(ret=options.tap.call($element,event,event.target)))):gesture==DOUBLE_TAP?phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!==PHASE_END||(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),clearTimeout(holdTimeout),doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("doubletap",[event.target]),options.doubleTap&&(ret=options.doubleTap.call($element,event,event.target))):gesture==LONG_TAP&&(phase!==PHASE_CANCEL&&phase!==PHASE_END||(clearTimeout(singleTapTimeout),doubleTapStartTime=null,$element.trigger("longtap",[event.target]),options.longTap&&(ret=options.longTap.call($element,event,event.target)))),ret}function validateSwipeDistance(){var valid=!0;return null!==options.threshold&&(valid=distance>=options.threshold),valid}function didSwipeBackToCancel(){var cancelled=!1;return null!==options.cancelThreshold&&null!==direction&&(cancelled=getMaxDistance(direction)-distance>=options.cancelThreshold),cancelled}function validatePinchDistance(){return null!==options.pinchThreshold?pinchDistance>=options.pinchThreshold:!0}function validateSwipeTime(){var result;return result=options.maxTimeThreshold?!(duration>=options.maxTimeThreshold):!0}function validateDefaultEvent(jqEvent,direction){if(options.preventDefaultEvents!==!1)if(options.allowPageScroll===NONE)jqEvent.preventDefault();else{var auto=options.allowPageScroll===AUTO;switch(direction){case LEFT:(options.swipeLeft&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=HORIZONTAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case RIGHT:(options.swipeRight&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=HORIZONTAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case UP:(options.swipeUp&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=VERTICAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case DOWN:(options.swipeDown&&auto||!auto&&options.allowPageScroll!=VERTICAL)&&jqEvent.preventDefault();break;case NONE:}}}function validatePinch(){var hasCorrectFingerCount=validateFingers(),hasEndPoint=validateEndPoint(),hasCorrectDistance=validatePinchDistance();return hasCorrectFingerCount&&hasEndPoint&&hasCorrectDistance}function hasPinches(){return!!(options.pinchStatus||options.pinchIn||options.pinchOut)}function didPinch(){return!(!validatePinch()||!hasPinches())}function validateSwipe(){var hasValidTime=validateSwipeTime(),hasValidDistance=validateSwipeDistance(),hasCorrectFingerCount=validateFingers(),hasEndPoint=validateEndPoint(),didCancel=didSwipeBackToCancel(),valid=!didCancel&&hasEndPoint&&hasCorrectFingerCount&&hasValidDistance&&hasValidTime;return valid}function hasSwipes(){return!!(options.swipe||options.swipeStatus||options.swipeLeft||options.swipeRight||options.swipeUp||options.swipeDown)}function didSwipe(){return!(!validateSwipe()||!hasSwipes())}function validateFingers(){return fingerCount===options.fingers||options.fingers===ALL_FINGERS||!SUPPORTS_TOUCH}function validateEndPoint(){return 0!==fingerData[0].end.x}function hasTap(){return!!options.tap}function hasDoubleTap(){return!!options.doubleTap}function hasLongTap(){return!!options.longTap}function validateDoubleTap(){if(null==doubleTapStartTime)return!1;var now=getTimeStamp();return hasDoubleTap()&&now-doubleTapStartTime<=options.doubleTapThreshold}function inDoubleTap(){return validateDoubleTap()}function validateTap(){return(1===fingerCount||!SUPPORTS_TOUCH)&&(isNaN(distance)||distance<options.threshold)}function validateLongTap(){return duration>options.longTapThreshold&&DOUBLE_TAP_THRESHOLD>distance}function didTap(){return!(!validateTap()||!hasTap())}function didDoubleTap(){return!(!validateDoubleTap()||!hasDoubleTap())}function didLongTap(){return!(!validateLongTap()||!hasLongTap())}function startMultiFingerRelease(event){previousTouchEndTime=getTimeStamp(),fingerCountAtRelease=event.touches.length+1}function cancelMultiFingerRelease(){previousTouchEndTime=0,fingerCountAtRelease=0}function inMultiFingerRelease(){var withinThreshold=!1;if(previousTouchEndTime){var diff=getTimeStamp()-previousTouchEndTime;diff<=options.fingerReleaseThreshold&&(withinThreshold=!0)}return withinThreshold}function getTouchInProgress(){return!($element.data(PLUGIN_NS+"_intouch")!==!0)}function setTouchInProgress(val){$element&&(val===!0?($element.bind(MOVE_EV,touchMove),$element.bind(END_EV,touchEnd),LEAVE_EV&&$element.bind(LEAVE_EV,touchLeave)):($element.unbind(MOVE_EV,touchMove,!1),$element.unbind(END_EV,touchEnd,!1),LEAVE_EV&&$element.unbind(LEAVE_EV,touchLeave,!1)),$element.data(PLUGIN_NS+"_intouch",val===!0))}function createFingerData(id,evt){var f={start:{x:0,y:0},last:{x:0,y:0},end:{x:0,y:0}};return f.start.x=f.last.x=f.end.x=evt.pageX||evt.clientX,f.start.y=f.last.y=f.end.y=evt.pageY||evt.clientY,fingerData[id]=f,f}function updateFingerData(evt){var id=void 0!==evt.identifier?evt.identifier:0,f=getFingerData(id);return null===f&&(f=createFingerData(id,evt)),f.last.x=f.end.x,f.last.y=f.end.y,f.end.x=evt.pageX||evt.clientX,f.end.y=evt.pageY||evt.clientY,f}function getFingerData(id){return fingerData[id]||null}function setMaxDistance(direction,distance){direction!=NONE&&(distance=Math.max(distance,getMaxDistance(direction)),maximumsMap[direction].distance=distance)}function getMaxDistance(direction){return maximumsMap[direction]?maximumsMap[direction].distance:void 0}function createMaximumsData(){var maxData={};return maxData[LEFT]=createMaximumVO(LEFT),maxData[RIGHT]=createMaximumVO(RIGHT),maxData[UP]=createMaximumVO(UP),maxData[DOWN]=createMaximumVO(DOWN),maxData}function createMaximumVO(dir){return{direction:dir,distance:0}}function calculateDuration(){return endTime-startTime}function calculateTouchesDistance(startPoint,endPoint){var diffX=Math.abs(startPoint.x-endPoint.x),diffY=Math.abs(startPoint.y-endPoint.y);return Math.round(Math.sqrt(diffX*diffX+diffY*diffY))}function calculatePinchZoom(startDistance,endDistance){var percent=endDistance/startDistance*1;return percent.toFixed(2)}function calculatePinchDirection(){return 1>pinchZoom?OUT:IN}function calculateDistance(startPoint,endPoint){return Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPoint.x-startPoint.x,2)+Math.pow(endPoint.y-startPoint.y,2)))}function calculateAngle(startPoint,endPoint){var x=startPoint.x-endPoint.x,y=endPoint.y-startPoint.y,r=Math.atan2(y,x),angle=Math.round(180*r/Math.PI);return 0>angle&&(angle=360-Math.abs(angle)),angle}function calculateDirection(startPoint,endPoint){if(comparePoints(startPoint,endPoint))return NONE;var angle=calculateAngle(startPoint,endPoint);return 45>=angle&&angle>=0?LEFT:360>=angle&&angle>=315?LEFT:angle>=135&&225>=angle?RIGHT:angle>45&&135>angle?DOWN:UP}function getTimeStamp(){var now=new Date;return now.getTime()}function getbounds(el){el=$(el);var offset=el.offset(),bounds={left:offset.left,right:offset.left+el.outerWidth(),top:offset.top,bottom:offset.top+el.outerHeight()};return bounds}function isInBounds(point,bounds){return point.x>bounds.left&&point.x<bounds.right&&point.y>bounds.top&&point.y<bounds.bottom}function comparePoints(pointA,pointB){return pointA.x==pointB.x&&pointA.y==pointB.y}var options=$.extend({},options),useTouchEvents=SUPPORTS_TOUCH||SUPPORTS_POINTER||!options.fallbackToMouseEvents,START_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerDown":"pointerdown":"touchstart":"mousedown",MOVE_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerMove":"pointermove":"touchmove":"mousemove",END_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerUp":"pointerup":"touchend":"mouseup",LEAVE_EV=useTouchEvents?SUPPORTS_POINTER?"mouseleave":null:"mouseleave",CANCEL_EV=SUPPORTS_POINTER?SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10?"MSPointerCancel":"pointercancel":"touchcancel",distance=0,direction=null,currentDirection=null,duration=0,startTouchesDistance=0,endTouchesDistance=0,pinchZoom=1,pinchDistance=0,pinchDirection=0,maximumsMap=null,$element=$(element),phase="start",fingerCount=0,fingerData={},startTime=0,endTime=0,previousTouchEndTime=0,fingerCountAtRelease=0,doubleTapStartTime=0,singleTapTimeout=null,holdTimeout=null;try{$element.bind(START_EV,touchStart),$element.bind(CANCEL_EV,touchCancel)}catch(e){$.error("events not supported "+START_EV+","+CANCEL_EV+" on jQuery.swipe")}this.enable=function(){return this.disable(),$element.bind(START_EV,touchStart),$element.bind(CANCEL_EV,touchCancel),$element},this.disable=function(){return removeListeners(),$element},this.destroy=function(){removeListeners(),$element.data(PLUGIN_NS,null),$element=null},this.option=function(property,value){if("object"==typeof property)options=$.extend(options,property);else if(void 0!==options[property]){if(void 0===value)return options[property];options[property]=value}else{if(!property)return options;$.error("Option "+property+" does not exist on jQuery.swipe.options")}return null}}var VERSION="1.6.17",LEFT="left",RIGHT="right",UP="up",DOWN="down",IN="in",OUT="out",NONE="none",AUTO="auto",SWIPE="swipe",PINCH="pinch",TAP="tap",DOUBLE_TAP="doubletap",LONG_TAP="longtap",HORIZONTAL="horizontal",VERTICAL="vertical",ALL_FINGERS="all",DOUBLE_TAP_THRESHOLD=10,PHASE_START="start",PHASE_MOVE="move",PHASE_END="end",PHASE_CANCEL="cancel",SUPPORTS_TOUCH="ontouchstart"in window,SUPPORTS_POINTER_IE10=window.navigator.msPointerEnabled&&!window.navigator.pointerEnabled&&!SUPPORTS_TOUCH,SUPPORTS_POINTER=(window.navigator.pointerEnabled||window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)&&!SUPPORTS_TOUCH,PLUGIN_NS="TouchSwipe",defaults={fingers:1,threshold:75,cancelThreshold:null,pinchThreshold:20,maxTimeThreshold:null,fingerReleaseThreshold:250,longTapThreshold:500,doubleTapThreshold:200,swipe:null,swipeLeft:null,swipeRight:null,swipeUp:null,swipeDown:null,swipeStatus:null,pinchIn:null,pinchOut:null,pinchStatus:null,click:null,tap:null,doubleTap:null,longTap:null,hold:null,triggerOnTouchEnd:!0,triggerOnTouchLeave:!1,allowPageScroll:"auto",fallbackToMouseEvents:!0,excludedElements:".noSwipe",preventDefaultEvents:!0};$.fn.swipe=function(method){var $this=$(this),plugin=$this.data(PLUGIN_NS);if(plugin&&"string"==typeof method){if(plugin[method])return plugin[method].apply(plugin,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));$.error("Method "+method+" does not exist on jQuery.swipe")}else if(plugin&&"object"==typeof method)plugin.option.apply(plugin,arguments);else if(!(plugin||"object"!=typeof method&&method))return init.apply(this,arguments);return $this},$.fn.swipe.version=VERSION,$.fn.swipe.defaults=defaults,$.fn.swipe.phases={PHASE_START:PHASE_START,PHASE_MOVE:PHASE_MOVE,PHASE_END:PHASE_END,PHASE_CANCEL:PHASE_CANCEL},$.fn.swipe.directions={LEFT:LEFT,RIGHT:RIGHT,UP:UP,DOWN:DOWN,IN:IN,OUT:OUT},$.fn.swipe.pageScroll={NONE:NONE,HORIZONTAL:HORIZONTAL,VERTICAL:VERTICAL,AUTO:AUTO},$.fn.swipe.fingers={ONE:1,TWO:2,THREE:3,FOUR:4,FIVE:5,ALL:ALL_FINGERS}});

/**
 * Slide and swipe menu (https://github.com/JoanClaret/slide-and-swipe-menu)
 *
 * @copyright Copyright 2013-2015 Joan claret
 * @license   MIT
 * @author    Joan Claret Teruel <dpam23 at gmail dot com>
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
 * Copyright (c) Joan Claret Teruel <dpam23 at gmail dot com>
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the 'Software'), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED 'AS IS', WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */


;(function($, document, window, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    var slideAndSwipe =

        $.fn.slideAndSwipe = function(options) {

            var nav = $(this); // get the element to swipe
            var navWidth = -nav.outerWidth();
            var transInitial = navWidth;
   var unit = 'px';

            // get settings
            var settings = $.extend({
                triggerOnTouchEnd   : true,
                swipeStatus         : swipeStatus,
                allowPageScroll     : 'vertical',
                threshold           : 100,
                excludedElements    : 'label, button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe',
                speed               : 280,
    percentage          : true

            }, options );
   if (settings.percentage) {
    navWidth = -100;
    unit = '%';
            }
            nav.swipe(settings);

            /**
             * Catch each phase of the swipe.
             * move : we drag the navigation
             * cancel : open navigation
             * end : close navigation
             */
            function swipeStatus(event, phase, direction, distance) {
                if(phase == 'start') {
                    if(nav.hasClass('ssm-nav-visible')) {
                        transInitial = 0;
                    } else {
                        transInitial = 0;
                    }
                }
                var mDistance;

                if (phase == 'move' && (direction == 'left')) {
                    if(transInitial < 0) {

                        mDistance = transInitial - distance;
                    } else {
                        mDistance = -distance;
                    }

                    scrollNav(mDistance, 0);

                } else if (phase == 'move' && direction == 'right') {
                    if(transInitial < 0) {
                        mDistance = transInitial + distance;
                    } else {
                        mDistance = distance;
                    }
                    scrollNav(mDistance, 0);
                } else if (phase == 'cancel' && (direction == 'right') && transInitial === 0) {
                    scrollNav(0, settings.speed);
                } else if (phase == 'end' && (direction == 'right')) {

                       hideNavigation();
                } else if ((phase == 'end' || phase == 'cancel') && (direction == 'left')) {
                    console.log('end');
                }
            }

            /**
             * Browser detect
             */
            function isSafari() {
                return /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
            }

            function isChrome() {
                return /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
            }

            /**
             * Manually update the position of the nav on drag
             */
            function scrollNav(distance, duration) {
                nav.css('transition-duration', (duration / 1000).toFixed(1) + 's');

                // if(distance >= 0) {
                //     distance = 0;
                // }
                if(distance <= 0) {
                    distance = 0;
                }
                if(isSafari() || isChrome()) {
                   //nav.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(' + distance + 'px,0)');
     nav.css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(' + distance + unit + ',0)');
    }
                else{
                  // nav.css('transform', 'translate(' + distance + 'px,0)');
     nav.css('transform', 'translate(' + distance + unit + ',0)');
    }
                if(distance == '0') {
                    $('.ssm-toggle-nav').addClass('ssm-nav-visible');
                    $('html').addClass('is-navOpen');
                    $('.ssm-overlay').fadeIn();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Open / close by click on burger icon
             */
            var hideNavigation = (function() {
                nav.removeClass('ssm-nav-visible');
                scrollNav(-280, settings.speed);
                $('html').removeClass('is-navOpen');
                $('.ssm-overlay').fadeOut();
    nav.css('transform', 'translate(100%,0)');
            });

            var showNavigation = (function() {
                nav.addClass('ssm-nav-visible');
                scrollNav(0, settings.speed);
            });

            $('.ssm-toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
                if(nav.hasClass('ssm-nav-visible')) {
                    hideNavigation();
                }
                else{
                    showNavigation();

                }
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    ;
})(window.jQuery || window.$, document, window);



/*
 * Export as a CommonJS module
 */
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = slideAndSwipe;
}


$('#proposal-panel').slideAndSwipe();
```

```css
#proposal-panel {
 background: #333333;
 width: 58%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 padding: 15px 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 /*overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: visible;*/
   transform: translate(100%,0);
}

/*Add to panel style sheet or header sheet*/
/* overlay layer */
.ssm-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* prevent scroll when panel is open */
.is-navOpen{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ssm-toggle-nav" href="#" title="Open / close">Open</a>
 <div id="proposal-panel" class="swipe">
  <h3 id="panel-title">Proposal</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="ssm-overlay ssm-toggle-nav"></div>
```